# (Very Simple) Get next element in menu?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, optionmenu

i'm trying to write a very simple script. As you can see i'm a big noob in Python.
I created a Tkinter option menu containing 3 options.
When i press the "n" key, i want my menu to be set on the next option.
So the default value is "banana", when i press "n" one time it has to be "apple", then "coco", then "banana" etc...
Everything works right I just dont know what to write to get the next option.

```
fruitmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, fruit, "banana", "apple", "coco")

fruit.set("banana") # default value

while True:
        root.update()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('n'):   
                print('Next Fruit')
                ???
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Bindings and Events](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events).

Comment: Keepin in mind, using a `while` will freeze your GUI for as long as that loop is done

Answer (score 0):

First, `keyboard.is_pressed('n')` is `root.bind('n', func)`. Second, to select the next option in the menu, you can save those options in a list or other container and then check which one you're at and go to the next one. Put that logic in the callback function.

```
fruits = '0123456789ABCDEF' # or a list ['0', '1'...] etc.
fruitmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, fruit, *fruits)
def func(event=None):
    fruit.set(fruits[(fruits.index(fruit.get())+1)%len(fruits)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works. I actually had to use keyboard.is_pressed('n') because i need the key press to be recognised even when im on another program.